# Add item to List<string> property

Tags: c#, list, class, object, addition

How could I add a new item to my list?

This is my object list or whatever people call this

```
class WordListsAll
{
    public int idAll { get; set; }
    public string wordEnAll { get; set; }
    public string translationAll { get; set; }
    public List<string> videosOfSelectedWord { get; set; }
}
```

All I want is to add a new item to videosOfSelectedWord list property.

What is the best way of doing this?

```
foreach (var item in q)
{
      count++;
      oWordListsAll.Add(new WordListsAll
      {
           idAll = count,
           wordEnAll = item.Element("Word").Value,
           translationAll = item.Element("Translation").Value,
           ///////////////here is my goal///////////////////
           videosOfSelectedWord.Add(myCustomString)
       });
}
```

Sometimes I want to come back and add a new myCustomString to the previously created instances. Imagin there was a word "hello" with the video name of "Dexter" and again there is a word "hello" but this time with the video name of "Breaking Bad".

How could I add these video names to my property list of videosOfSelectedWord?

Comment: How to add a new item to a list<string> property multiple times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to assign the list itself - you can do that with a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
foreach (var item in q)
{
    count++;
    oWordListsAll.Add(new WordListsAll
    {
        idAll = count,
        wordEnAll = item.Element("Word").Value,
        translationAll = item.Element("Translation").Value,
        videosOfSelectedWord = new List<string> { myCustomString }
    });
}
```

To add to an existing item, perhaps something like this (not totally clear from your question, you probably should do some reading):

```
//should really use a dictionary, this is just to show a simple example
var alreadyExists = videosOfSelectedWord.FirstOrDefault(x => x.wordEnAll == item);
if(alreadyExists !=null)
{
    alreadyExists.videosOfSelectedWord.Add(myCustomString);
    alreadyExists.idAll++;
}
else
{
    //new item
}
```

(As an aside your names really should follow the naming convention so properties should be capitalized)

Comment: you know I want to add a new myCustomString(new video name) each time there is a repetition for wordEnAll(English word exist in video text).
I will access my object based on id and want to add new myCustomString to the videoOfSelectedWord property. Is if possible?

Comment: currently you are creating a new `WordListsAll` instance every single time - can you describe better what you are trying to achieve as part of your question?